# Consulta SQl sobre asignaciones de valores

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedure

tengo una duda, tengo que hacer un procedure en SQL que permite hacer ingreso de registros, pero al momento de asignar valor, tengo que asignar valor a los parámetros que son varchar?

```
create procedure ejercicio_1
@id_producto int,
@producto varchar(50),
@descripcion varchar(50),
@id_categoria int

as
begin

  declare @id_producto int, @producto varchar(50), @descripcion varchar(50), @id_categoria int
  set @id_producto = 0,
  set @id_categoria = 0, 
  set @producto = 0,
  set @descripcion = 0,

end
```

Comment: ¿Por qué usas tantas etiquetas? No las uses a la ligera, por favor lee [el recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y date una vuelta por [el centro de ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help). [¿Qué son las etiquetas, y cómo debo usarlas?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)

Comment: Cuando lo publique solo puse 5 que son las que me pedían.

Comment: Son máximo cinco. La gente mira las etiquetas y ve si sabe de esos temas para intentar ayudar. Sobre la pregunta, a qué asignación te refieres? A los parámetros del procedimiento? A las variables que tienes dentro? Por favor edita la pregunta y aclara un poco a qué te refieres.